# LINQ filter a database list with another database list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have tried to find an answer for this.

I am using LINQ and trying to filter a database list with another list, to remove countries from a list of countries where a member is already a citizen.

```
var currentCitizenships = DbContext.Citizenships
            .Where(c => c.MemberId == CurrentUser.MemberId)
            .Include(c => c.Country)
            .ToList();

var filtered = DbContext.Countries
            .Where(c => !currentCitizenships.Any(current => current.Country.CountryId == c.CountryId));
```

I am getting a `Not supported exception` with the following message:

`Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.EntityFramework.Models.Citizenship'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

**Two Solutions Worked**

1. Remove the ToList() of the first query.
2. The selected answer.

I've picked 1. due to using less lines and was a simpler solution with the same result.

Comment: Second query is throwing the exception. I wouldn't be against combining the queries either if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Try removing .ToList() from the first query.

Comment: @Harsh That also worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it cannot create a valid SQL query using whatever is stored in `currentCitizenships`.

Get the list of country id's you need first, and then modify your query to use `Contains` on the simple collection of integers (or whatever `CountryId` is) instead.

```
var countryIds = currentCitizenships.Select(x => x.Country.CountryId).ToList();

var filtered = DbContext.Countries.Where(c => !countryIds.Contains(c.CountryId));
```